# jquery- adding rows based on css property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have around 50 rows of data. The css property of many rows are set to default:none.

I want to add only the data of rows whose display is not none. is there anything in jquery for this.

My [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htzqL/)

current i am calculating it like and getting all wrong

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".sum").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    $('table tr td:nth-of-type(1)').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($('table tr td:nth-of-type(1)').text()) || 0;
    $('.sum').text(" "+total);
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sum").click(function () {
        var total = 0;

        //all first td elements of the table where tr id visible
        $('table td:nth-of-type(1):visible').each(function(){
            total += parseFloat($(this).text()) || 0;
        })

        //display the total
        $(this).text(" " + total);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xVNSF/)